# Python: How to write a lambda that accesses instance variables

Tags: python

I am writing a class that stores credentials. The credential can have a `password_getter` attribute which stores a lambda that will get the password on-demand. This getter needs access to `self.username` in order to function. How can this be accomplished? Consider the following setup:

```
class Credential:
    """Defines one username and password combination, and how to get them."""

    def __init__(self, username: str, password_getter: callable):
        self.username = username
        self._password_getter = password_getter

    @property
    def password(self) -> str:
        self.password = self._password_getter()
        return self.password
```

Then we define a new credential:

```
cred = Credential(
    username="test",
    password_getter=lambda self: self.username+"_pass",
)
assert cred.password == "test_pass"
```

The above is non-functional due to `self` not existing during definition, but it suggests what I'm trying to do: Access the current value of `cred.username` from inside the lambda.

For some context as to why this is happening; the function in production actually goes out to a password vault api and requests the password for the given username.

Comment: You need to pass `self` when calling the getter, or you use `lambda: cred.username + '_pass'`.

Comment: The easiest way is to do :
```python
username="test"
cred = Credential(
    username="username",
    password_getter=lambda : username+"_pass",
)
```

Comment: The problem is that another part of the code could theoretically change the `username` later. The `getter` needs to be able to use the current `username` in its response.

Comment: so why isn't this fn just a method on `Credential` if it needs access to state stored on the instance?  You can still call out to any 3rd party fn you need.

Comment: Because `Credential` just defines a framework for storing and retrieving usernames and passwords. The actual `getter` code varies significantly between credentials, ranging from checking environment variables to querying remote APIs. I could subclass `Credential` for each cred, but that just seemed bulky if I could use lambdas.

Comment: @WykoterHaar fair: the answer below is the usual way to do that.  I'm sure you know this, but you're really just using *functions*---though I can't think of any examples right now I've definitely encountered the paradigm 'x should be a callable which will recieve the instance as it's first arg' plenty of times.  Only mentioning re. lambdas because sometimes the get treated as somehow special, and not merely limited anonymous fns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Callable` you pass in has no intrinsic connection to the instance, so your two options are to give it implicit or explicit access. Implicit would rely on simple closures:

```
cred = Credential(
    username="test",
    password_getter=lambda: cred.username + "_pass",
)
```

The problem here is if you reassign `cred` later and it refers to the wrong instance when trying to get the password.

The explicit alternative is:

```
cred = Credential(
    username="test",
    password_getter=lambda instance: instance.username + "_pass",
)
```

```
...
    @property
    def password(self) -> str:
        self.password = self._password_getter(self)
```

The class explicitly passes it`self` to the password getter. So it should be typed as `Callable[[Credentials], str]`, i.e. something that receives an instance of the class as argument and is expected to return a string.

Comment: Nice! I totally missed the obvious choice to pass `self` in `self._password_getter(self)`. Thanks for that!